# Linux C read file UNICODE formatted text (notepad Windows)

Tags: c, linux, unicode

Is there a way to read a text file, under Linux with C, saved on Windows as "UNICODE" with notepad?
The text in Linux with `nano` editor looks like:

```
��T^@e^@s^@t^@
^@
```

but under `vi` editor is read properly as:

```
Test
```

I must specify the text is normal strings ANSI (no Unicode characters or foreign languages related).
Tried like this but no result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
   char *loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
   setlocale(LC_ALL, loc);
   FILE * f = fopen("unicode.txt", "r");
   wint_t c;

   while((c = fgetwc(f)) != WEOF) {
      wprintf(L"%lc\n", c);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

Forgot to mention the file format is `Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text` or `UTF-16LE`

Comment: Can you convert the file using `iconv -f unicode -t utf8 < infile > outfile` ?  Or do you need to edit the file itself?

Comment: I know how to convert it with iconv, the problem is I need to do it from my code without relying on external tools.

Comment: No there's no way... vi works on miracles, not on C, therefore it's special... really, if you don't know about locales and libiconv and stuff, whatever happened to the dumb method of using every other  byte?

Comment: If your code needs to "handle" this, you can just open the file, read the bytes, and live with them the way they are.  If you imply that you want to convert the unicode to something else (ansi) then you should use a proper tool for that, and libiconv is of course a good idea then.  Doing it yourself (by skipping every other byte) would pose problems if there is a character with code >255 in the text (a Chinese character or whatever).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include `<wchar.h>`, set an UTF-8 locale (`setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8")` is fine), open the file or stream in byte-oriented mode (`handle=fopen(filename, "rb")`, `fwide(handle,-1)`, i.e. in not-wide mode). Then you can use

```
wint_t getwc_utf16le(FILE *const in)
{
    int lo, hi, code, also;

    if ((lo = getc(in)) == EOF)
        return WEOF;

    if ((hi = getc(in)) == EOF)
        return lo; /* Or abort; input sequence ends prematurely */

    code = lo + 256 * hi;
    if (code < 0xD800 || code > 0xDBFF)
        return code; /* Or abort; input sequence is not UTF16-LE */

    if ((lo = getc(in)) == EOF)
        return code; /* Or abort; input sequence ends prematurely */

    if ((hi = getc(in)) == EOF) {
        ungetc(lo, in);
        return code; /* Or abort; input sequence ends prematurely */
    }

    /* Note: if ((lo + 256*hi) < 0xDC00 || (lo + 256*hi) > 0xDFFF)
     *       the input sequence is not valid UTF16-LE. */
    return 0x10000 + ((code & 0x3FF) << 10) + ((lo + 256 * hi) & 0x3FF);
}
```

to read code points from such an input file, assuming it contains UTF16-LE data.

The above function is more permissive than strictly necessary, but it does parse all UTF16-LE I could throw at it (including the sometimes problematic U+100000..U+10FFFF code points), so if the input is correct, this function should handle it just fine.

Because the locale is set to UTF-8 in Linux, and Linux implementations support the full Unicode set, the code points match the ones produced by above functions, and you can safely use wide character functions (from `<wchar.h>`) to handle the input.

Often the first character in the file is BOM, *"byte-order mark"*, `0xFEFF`. You can ignore it if it is the first character in the file. Elsewhere it is the zero-width non-breaking space. In my experience, those two bytes at the start of a file that is supposed to be text, is quite reliable indicator that the file is UTF16-LE. (So, you could peek at the first two bytes, and if they match those, assume it is UTF16-LE.)

Remember that wide-character end-of-file is `WEOF`, not `EOF`.

Hope this helps.

---

Edited 20150505: Here is a helper function one could use instead, to read inputs (using low-level `unistd.h` interface), converting to UTF-8: `read_utf8.h`:

```
#ifndef   READ_UTF8_H
#define   READ_UTF8_H

/* Read input from file descriptor fd,
 * convert it to UTF-8 (using "UTF8//TRANSLIT" iconv conversion),
 * and appending to the specified buffer.
 *    (*dataptr)   points to a dynamically allocated buffer (may reallocate),
 *    (*sizeptr)   points to the size allocated for that buffer,
 *    (*usedptr)   points to the amount of data already in the buffer.
 * You may initialize the values to NULL,0,0, in which case they will
 * be dynamically allocated as needed.
*/
int read_utf8(char **dataptr, size_t *sizeptr, size_t *usedptr, const int fd, const char *const charset);

#endif /* READ_UTF8_H */
```

`read_utf8.c`:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iconv.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define   INPUT_CHUNK  16384
#define   OUTPUT_CHUNK  8192

int read_utf8(char **dataptr, size_t *sizeptr, size_t *usedptr, const int fd, const char *const charset)
{
    char    *data;
    size_t   size;
    size_t   used;

    char    *input_data;
    size_t   input_size, input_head, input_tail;
    int      input_more;

    iconv_t  conversion = (iconv_t)-1;

    if (!dataptr || !sizeptr || !usedptr || fd == -1 || !charset || !*charset)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    if (*dataptr) {
        data = *dataptr;
        size = *sizeptr;
        used = *usedptr;
        if (used > size)
            return errno = EINVAL;
    } else {
        data = NULL;
        size = 0;
        used = 0;
    }

    conversion = iconv_open("UTF8//TRANSLIT", charset);
    if (conversion == (iconv_t)-1)
        return errno = ENOTSUP;

    input_size = INPUT_CHUNK;
    input_data = malloc(input_size);
    if (!input_data) {
        if (conversion != (iconv_t)-1)
            iconv_close(conversion);
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return 0;
    }
    input_head = 0;
    input_tail = 0;
    input_more = 1;

    while (1) {

        if (input_tail > input_head) {
            if (input_head > 0) {
                memmove(input_data, input_data + input_head, input_tail - input_head);
                input_tail -= input_head;
                input_head  = 0;
            }
        } else {
            input_head = 0;
            input_tail = 0;
        }

        if (input_more && input_tail < input_size) {
            ssize_t n;

            do {
                n = read(fd, input_data + input_tail, input_size - input_tail);
            } while (n == (ssize_t)-1 && errno == EINTR);

            if (n > (ssize_t)0)
                input_tail += n;
            else
            if (n == (ssize_t)0)
                input_more = 0;
            else
            if (n != (ssize_t)-1) {
                free(input_data);
                iconv_close(conversion);
                return errno = EIO;
            } else {
                const int errcode = errno;
                free(input_data);
                iconv_close(conversion);
                return errno = errcode;
            }
        }

        if (input_head == 0 && input_tail == 0)
            break;

        if (used + OUTPUT_CHUNK > size) {
            size = (used / (size_t)OUTPUT_CHUNK + (size_t)2) * (size_t)OUTPUT_CHUNK;
            data = realloc(data, size);
            if (!data) {
                free(input_data);
                iconv_close(conversion);
                return errno = ENOMEM;
            }
            *dataptr = data;
            *sizeptr = size;
        }

        {
            char   *source_ptr = input_data + input_head;
            size_t  source_len = input_tail - input_head;

            char   *target_ptr = data + used;
            size_t  target_len = size - used;

            size_t  n;

            n = iconv(conversion, &source_ptr, &source_len, &target_ptr, &target_len);
            if (n == (size_t)-1 && errno == EILSEQ) {
                free(input_data);
                iconv_close(conversion);
                return errno = EILSEQ;
            }

            if (source_ptr == input_data + input_head && target_ptr == data + used) {
                free(input_data);
                iconv_close(conversion);
                return errno = EDEADLK;
            }

            input_head = (size_t)(source_ptr - input_data);
            used = (size_t)(target_ptr - data);

            *usedptr = used;
        }
    }

    free(input_data);
    iconv_close(conversion);

    if (used + 16 >= size) {
        size = (used | 15) + 17;
        data = realloc(data, size);
        if (!data)
            return errno = ENOMEM;
        *dataptr = data;
        *sizeptr = size;
        memset(data + used, 0, size - used);
    } else
    if (used + 32 < size)
        memset(data + used, 0, size - used);
    else
        memset(data + used, 0, 32);

    return errno = 0;
}
```

and an example program, `example.c`, on how to use it:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "read_utf8.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char   *file_buffer = NULL;
    size_t  file_allocd = 0;
    size_t  file_length = 0;
    int     fd;

    if (argc != 3 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s FILENAME CHARSET\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s FILENAME CHARSET//IGNORE\n", argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    do {
        fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | O_NOCTTY);
    } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (read_utf8(&file_buffer, &file_allocd, &file_length, fd, argv[2])) {
        if (errno == ENOTSUP)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unsupported character set.\n", argv[2]);
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    errno = EIO;
    if (close(fd)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%s: read %zu bytes, allocated %zu.\n", argv[1], file_length, file_allocd);
    if (file_length > 0)
        if (fwrite(file_buffer, file_length, 1, stdout) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to standard output.\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This lets you read (either into an empty, dynamically allocated buffer, or append to an existing dynamically allocated buffer) using any character set supported by your system (use `iconv --list` to see the list), auto-converting the contents to UTF-8.

It uses a temporary input buffer (of `INPUT_CHUNK` bytes) to read the file part by part, and reallocates the output buffer in multiples of `OUTPUT_CHUNK` bytes, keeping at least `OUTPUT_CHUNK` bytes available for each conversion. The constants may need a bit of tuning for different use cases; they're by no means optimal or even suggested values. Larger ones lead to faster code, especially for `INPUT_CHUNK`, as most filesystems perform better when reading large chunks (`2097152` is suggested size currently, if I/O performance is important) -- but you should have `OUTPUT_CHUNK` at similar size, or perhaps twice that, to reduce the number of reallocations needed. (You can trim the resulting buffer afterwards, to `used+1` bytes, using `realloc()`, to avoid memory waste.)

Comment: Thank you! I was just moving to `iconv`

Comment: @xtmrx: Using [`iconv_open()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv_open.3.html), [`iconv()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv.3.html), [`iconv_close()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv_close.3.html) is a much more portable and versatile option, if there is a possibility you might encounter any other character sets. Well, all of the Unicode variants (UTF-16, UTF16-LE, UTF16-BE, UCS-2, UCS-4) are trivially converted to and from UTF-8, so simple read-character functions like mine above are probably easier to implement..

Comment: @bsteo: And the reason for unaccepting this answer, after more than a year after initially accepting it, is?

Comment: Sorry, messed up with my phone :-/

Comment: @bsteo: Ah, okay. I was just wondering. I decided to add an `iconv()`-based approach, as an example. It is not optimized or verified to work correctly in all cases (I do tend to be very careful about error checking, and having the code behave even in problem situations), but it definitely should do for an example, or a starting point.